# pandas drop row below each row containing an 'na'

Tags: python, pandas

i have a dataframe with, say, 4 columns `[['a','b','c','d']]`, to which I add another column `['total']` containing the sum of all the other columns for each row. I then add another column `['growth of total']` with the growth rate of the total.

some of the values in `[['a','b','c','d']]` are blank, rendering the `['total']` column invalid for these rows. I can easily get rid of these rows with df.dropna(how='any').

However, my growth rate will be invalid not only for rows with missing values in `[['a','b','c','d']]`, but also for the following row. How do I drop all these rows?

Comment: Can you not just fill them `df.fillna(0)`? and then sum them?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I already take care of the rows with empty values. My problem is that I also need to get rid of each row following a row with an empty value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC correctly you can use `notnull` with `all` to mask off any rows with `NaN` and any rows that follow `NaN` rows:

```
In [43]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,np.NaN, 2, 3,np.NaN], 'b':[np.NaN, 1,2,3,4], 'c':[0, np.NaN,2,3,4]})
df

Out[43]:
    a   b   c
0   0 NaN   0
1 NaN   1 NaN
2   2   2   2
3   3   3   3
4 NaN   4   4

In [44]:
df[df.notnull().all(axis=1) & df.shift().notnull().all(axis=1)]

Out[44]:
   a  b  c
3  3  3  3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option that I think does what you're looking for:

```
In [76]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(40).reshape(10,4))

In [77]: df.ix[1,2] = np.nan

In [78]: df.ix[6,1] = np.nan

In [79]: df['total'] = df.sum(axis=1, skipna=False)

In [80]: df
Out[80]:
    0   1   2   3  total
0   0   1   2   3      6
1   4   5 NaN   7    NaN
2   8   9  10  11     38
3  12  13  14  15     54
4  16  17  18  19     70
5  20  21  22  23     86
6  24 NaN  26  27    NaN
7  28  29  30  31    118
8  32  33  34  35    134
9  36  37  38  39    150

In [81]: df['growth'] = df['total'].iloc[1:] - df['total'].values[:-1]

In [82]: df
Out[82]:
    0   1   2   3  total  growth
0   0   1   2   3      6     NaN
1   4   5 NaN   7    NaN     NaN
2   8   9  10  11     38     NaN
3  12  13  14  15     54      16
4  16  17  18  19     70      16
5  20  21  22  23     86      16
6  24 NaN  26  27    NaN     NaN
7  28  29  30  31    118     NaN
8  32  33  34  35    134      16
9  36  37  38  39    150      16
```